# How to use ng-if with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple nav object setup that lists the nav items (and whether they should appear in the primary nav or not). It seems though when I try to mix ng-if with ng-repeat, things fall apart, but when I mix ng-show with ng-repeat it works fine (but I end up with a bunch of hidden elements that I don't want appended to the DOM).

```
   <section class="nav">
        <a  ng-repeat="(key, item) in route.routes"
            ng-href="{{key}}"
            ng-show="item.nav"
        >
                {{item.label}}
        </a>
    </section>
```

But the following doesn't work (note the `ng-show` is now `ng-if`):

```
    <section class="nav">
    <a  ng-repeat="(key, item) in route.routes"
        ng-href="{{key}}"
        ng-if="item.nav"
    >
            {{item.label}}
    </a>
</section>
```

The routes object looks like

```
routes: {
    '/home': { label: 'Home', nav: true },
    '/contact': { label: 'Contact', nav: false},
   // etc
}
```

I receive the following error when trying to use `ng-if`:

> Error: Multiple directives [ngIf, ngRepeat] asking for transclusion on:

I guess it's trying to tell me that I can't state it's declaration for existing twice. I could use `ng-if` on an inner element, but I think I would still end up with a bunch of empty outer `a` tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's probably a better solution, but after reading the replies above, you can try making your own custom filter:

```
angular.module('yourModule').filter('filterNavItems', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var inputArray = [];

    for(var item in input) {
      inputArray.push(input[item]);
    }

    return inputArray.filter(function(v) { return v.nav; });
  };
});
```

Then to use it:

```
<section class="nav">
    <a  ng-repeat="(key, item) in routes | filterNavItems"
        ng-href="{{key}}">
            {{item.label}}
    </a>
</section>
```

Here's the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/srMbxK?p=preview

Comment: Why do you copy the input into inputArray?  It seems to work fine if you just filter on the input array directly.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `ng-if` you should use a filter (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) on you `ng-repeat` to exclude certain items from your list.

Comment: As mentioned in @Skimberks answer, filter doesn't support objects without additional plugins

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well, and found a couple ways to solve it.

The first thing I tried was to combine `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` into a custom directive. I'll push that up to github sometime soon, but it's kludgy.

The simpler way to do it is to modify your `route.routes` collection (or create a placeholder collection)

```
$scope.filteredRoutes = {};
angular.forEach($scope.route.routes, function(item, key) {
    if (item.nav) { $scope.filteredRoutes[key] = item; }
};
```

and in your view

```
...
<a  ng-repeat="(key, item) in filteredRoutes"
...
```

If you need it to be dynamically updated, just set up watches, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one-liner using [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
$scope.filteredRoutes = $filter('filter')($scope.route.routes, function(route){
  return route.nav;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a filter in your `ng-repeat` instead of using `ng-if`.

This should work:

```
<section class="nav">
    <a  ng-repeat="(key, item) in route.routes | filter:item.nav"
        ng-href="{{key}}">
            {{item.label}}
    </a>
</section>
```

Warning: I haven't actually tested this code.

Comment: filter doesn't work with objects, [unfortunately](http://plnkr.co/edit/RYOlWAGJZ2kgRYDKa0L0?p=preview). [This module](https://github.com/floydsoft/angular-underscore) seems like it would work though.

Comment: Although I didn't know about the filter filter. Whenever I searched for filter, I just thought that whenever it said `filter` it meant angular filters in general, and not an actual array filter.

Comment: Yep - I was just trialing this way and it's bugging out. Thanks though